# How to increment product quantity in cart using server actions in nextjs13

Tags: mongodb, next.js, prisma, cart, next.js13

I am working on ecommerce project in nextjs 13 using server action i have created cart page where i am able to add products to cart but whenever i try to add same product into the cart instead of incrementing the product quantity by 1 my code shows me error. i know the error is in action.ts file where i am updating the product but i couldn't get the solution that's why i am here. if anyone have solution then please guide me.Here is the error

```
PrismaClientValidationError: 
Invalid `prisma.cart.update()` invocation:

{
  where: {
    id: "653591cee2c809f9c4601409"
  },
  data: {
    quantity: {
    ~~~~~~~~
      increment: 1
    },
?   createdAt?: DateTime | DateTimeFieldUpdateOperationsInput,
?   updatedAt?: DateTime | DateTimeFieldUpdateOperationsInput,
?   items?: CartItemUpdateManyWithoutCartNestedInput
  }
}

Unknown argument `quantity`. Available options are marked with ?.
    at async IncrementProductQuantity (./app/products/[id]/actions.ts:19:9)
```

Here is the action.ts file code

```
"use server"

import { createCart, getCart } from "@/lib/db/cart"
import prisma from "@/lib/db/prisma";
import {revalidatePath} from "next/cache";

export async function IncrementProductQuantity(productId:string){
    const cart=await getCart() ?? await createCart();
    const articleInCart=cart.items.find(item=>item.productId===productId);

    if (articleInCart) {
        await prisma.cart.update({
          where: { id: articleInCart.id },
          data: { quantity: { increment: 1 } },
        });
      }
    else{
        await prisma.cartItem.create({
            data:{
                cartId:cart.id,
                productId,
                quantity:1
            }
        })
    }
    revalidatePath("/products/[id]")
}
```

here is my cart.ts code

```
import { cookies } from "next/dist/client/components/headers";
import prisma from "./prisma";
import { Prisma } from "@prisma/client";

export type CartWithProducts = Prisma.CartGetPayload<{
    include: { items: { include: { product: true } } };
  }>;
  
  export type CartItemWithProduct = Prisma.CartItemGetPayload<{
    include: { product: true };
  }>;
  
  export type ShoppingCart = CartWithProducts & {
    size: number;
    subtotal: number;
  };

export async function getCart(): Promise<ShoppingCart | null> {
   
    const localCartId = cookies().get("localCartId")?.value;
    const cart = localCartId
      ? await prisma.cart.findUnique({
          where: { id: localCartId },
          include: { items: { include: { product: true } } },
        })
      : null;


  if (!cart) {
    return null;
  }

  return {
    ...cart,
    size: cart.items.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.quantity, 0),
    subtotal: cart.items.reduce(
      (acc, item) => acc + item.quantity * item.product.price,
      0
    ),
  };
}

export async function createCart(): Promise<ShoppingCart> {

  const  newCart = await prisma.cart.create({
      data: { },
    });

    // Note: Needs encryption + secure settings in real production app
    cookies().set("localCartId", newCart.id);

  return {
    ...newCart,
    items:[],
    size: 0,
    subtotal: 0,
  }}
```

Add to cart button component code is here

```
"use client"

import { useState, useTransition } from "react"

interface AddToCartButtonProps {
    productId:string,
    incrementProductQuantity:(productId:string)=>Promise<void>
}
export default function AddToCartButton({productId,incrementProductQuantity}:AddToCartButtonProps){
    const[isPending,startTransition]=useTransition();
    const[success,setSuccess]=useState(false)
    return(
        <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
            <button
            className="btn btn-primary"
            onClick={()=>{
                setSuccess(false);
                startTransition(async ()=>{
                    await incrementProductQuantity(productId);
                    setSuccess(true)
                })
            }}
            >
                Add To Cart
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="h-5 w-5" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                <path stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" d="M3 3h2l.4 2M7 13h10l4-8H5.4M7 13L5.4 5M7 13l-2.293 2.293c-.63.63-.184 1.707.707 1.707H17m0 0a2 2 0 100 4 2 2 0 000-4zm-8 2a2 2 0 11-4 0 2 2 0 014 0z" />
            </svg>
            </button>
            {isPending && <span className="loading loading-spinner loading-lg"/>}
            {!isPending && success && <span className="text-success font-bold">Added To Cart</span>}
        </div>
    )
}
```

CartItem Model in prisma is as below

```
model CartItem {
  id        String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  productId String  @db.ObjectId
  product   Product @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  quantity  Int?
  cartId    String  @db.ObjectId
  cart      Cart    @relation(fields: [cartId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@map("cartItems")
}
```